# Google V3 and YouTube API Search Result is not returning complete/full description or snippet

Tags: google-api-php-client

We are integrating Google V3 & Youtube Search APIs. Below are the service URL queries. We found search result from both returning partial characters (say

first 160 chars) of "description" (for youtube) or "snippet" (for google). We need full description or sinippet information. We need full description or

snippet from search result, we went through all API params, but not helping much.

Please require your valuable suggestion/help.

### Youtube API Search:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?safeSearch=strict&part=id
%2Csnippet&q=azure&maxResults=1&lr=en&key=AIzaSyCDgJ06vaf7VGTZU7M49Hy_xoZteEpdeDM&callback=jQuery19105663580358959734_1420535665057&_=1420535665066

### Output (JSON):

"description": "This video is part of a blog post at:I do a lot of demos. I write a lot of blog posts. T...",

Thanks,
Manohara M